# Why the bash command 'sed -i' doesn't replace the string in the file?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, environment-variables

**Environment**

Mac OS Catalina 10.15
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

**Problem**

I am trying to add some new value in my environment variable PATH in $HOME/.zshrc file.
I am using a bash script in Catalina Mac OS X.
I am using the command "sed -I" to replace a string by another string in a file.

After so many hours of investigation because of the complexity of the command with special slash / characters in the path folders, I succeed to fix all the issues.

But there is no result at all. The string is not replaced!

In my code below, I am "echo" the value of the PATH variables in order to compare the strings in the output.

The `sed -i` command:

I use the "+" characters to separate the strong to be replaced and the new string because I am replacing some paths which contains some slash / characters:

```
sed -i '' "s+\"$PATH_VALUE\"+\"$NEW_PATH_VALUE\"+" $HOME/.zshrc
```

I use various styles and ways for this command which all bring the same result => no string were changed:

```
sed -i '' "s+$PATH_VALUE+$NEW_PATH_VALUE+" $HOME/.zshrc

sed -i '' "s+${PATH_VALUE}+${NEW_PATH_VALUE}+" $HOME/.zshrc

sed -i '' "s+${PATH_VALUE}+${NEW_PATH_VALUE}+" "$HOME"/.zshrc
```

etc...

**bash code:**

```
#! /bin/bash
#WE ADD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE PATH 
PATH_VALUE=$PATH

#IF THE PATH OF ADB IS ALREADY IN PATH, WE DO NOTHING 
if [[ "$PATH_VALUE" == *"$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD"* ]]; then
    echo "$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD is in PATH environment variable!"
#OTHERWISE WE ADD IT IN PATH VARIABLE 
else
    echo "$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD is NOT in PATH environment variable! We will add it."
    NEW_PATH_VALUE=$PATH_VALUE:$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD
    echo "PATH_VALUE is :"
    echo "$PATH_VALUE"
    echo "NEW_PATH_VALUE is :"
    echo "$NEW_PATH_VALUE"
    export PATH=$NEW_PATH_VALUE

#WE ADD IT IN THE PROFILE FILE 
echo "***** WE ADD NEW_PATH_VALUE IN THE PROFILE FILE CATALINA *****"
sed -i '' "s+\"$PATH_VALUE\"+\"$NEW_PATH_VALUE\"+" $HOME/.zshrc
```

**Output:**

```
ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD : /Users/gauthierbtz/Android/platform-tools
/Users/gauthierbtz/Android/platform-tools is NOT in PATH environment variable! We will add it.
PATH_VALUE is :
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/condabin
NEW_PATH_VALUE is :
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/gauthierbtz/Android/platform-tools
***** WE ADD NEW_PATH_VALUE IN THE PROFILE FILE CATALINA *****
```

And here the content of $HOME/.zshrc file:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<


PATH="/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/Android/cmdline-tools/tools/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Does anyone see what I am I doing wrong? Why the replacement doesn't work?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but >> append a string at the end of file, and I need to replace the value of PATH by the new value.

Comment: I tried `echo "$PATH_VALUE" | sed "s+$PATH_VALUE+$NEW_PATH_VALUE+"` and got the expected value `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/gauthierbtz/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/gauthierbtz/Android/platform-tools`, so if those are your real strings, there is nothing there that is causing a problem. Check that your cfg files haven't be corrupted with `cat -vet /path/to/file.cfg`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then `dos2unx /path/to/file.cfg` might solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but which .cfg file are you talking about? Sorry I am a Mac OS X newbie.

Comment: $HOME/.zshrc is a config file.

Comment: @shellter there is not ^M$ at the end of each line of my $HOME/.zshrc file.

Comment: I tried without the ' '  and it gave the same issue. No change was done.

Comment: I may be nitpicking, but `sed -i` is not a `"bash command"`.

Comment: OK, I just tested your `"\"$PATH_VALUE\""` version, I thought that might be a problem, but it worked as needed. As `^M$` wasn't a problem, I'm running out of ideas. I would try just `sed "+...+...+" $HOME/.zshrc > tstOutput; diff $HOME/.zshrc testOutput` (deliberately leaving out the `-i ''`) to eliminate anything about file access or other issues using `-i`. Good luck.

Comment: 1) are you testing your `sed` commands outside of your shell script, just on the cmd line? Get that to work first. 2) run your cmd-line tests with `set -vx; sed ..... ; set +vx` to get an exact picture of what the shell is processing. You can add those to your cmds in your shell script too. I think I'm out of ideas now. Hmm any chance you have Curly single or dbl quotes in your code, instead of `'` and `"` (straight single and dbl quotes). Mac users often get tripped up by this problem from their editor. Can't think of anything else now. Good luck!

Comment: @Roadowl : Yes, this seems to have boiled down to a `sed` problem, but given the larger context, and the O.P.s "hours of research" (which I believe), I'm willing to let the mistagging pass. Good luck to all!

Comment: Bzzt!? (record scratch!) ... In your section labeled `contents of $HOME/.zshrc`, the `PATH` variable shown there doesn't look at all like the `PATH_VALUE` var you have set in your script. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A simpler and more conventional solution is to add `PATH=$PATH:$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD` to the end of your shell's startup file. (Probably better to put the actual path rather than `$ADB_FOLDER_TO_ADD` unless you need to add it as a system variable for other reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

After have tested all the tricks suggested by helpers (Big Thanks to all of them), I suspect my system to be corrupted.

So I reboot my Mac OS, and it works with the command:

```
sed -i '' "s+${PATH_VALUE}+${NEW_PATH_VALUE}+" "$HOME"/.zshrc
```

CONCLUSION: As any OS of any devices of the world, when everything has been tested, a reboot could be the magic ultimate solution!

Thank you guys for your help